# How to change display property using javascript and sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for help changing the display property of a div class using javascript and sessionStorage. The sessionStorage variable is visible in console but I am stuck changing the CSS. I've used getElementByClassName and also getElementByID and neither will show/hide the blocks - I'm seeing both blocks - rather than just one block conditional on the value of the sessionStorage variable. Any clues welcome?

```js
function setUpPopupRegistrationForm() {

  $('.js-popup-register-button').on('click', function() {

    let storage = window.sessionStorage;
    let selectedRole = this.dataset.role;

    storage.clear('selectedRole');
    storage.setItem('selectedRole', selectedRole);

    var r1 = document.getElementByClassName("radiocustom")[0];
    var r2 = document.getElementByClassName("radiocustom2")[0];

    if (selectedRole == "investor-member") {

      r1.style.display = "block";
      r2.style.display = "none";

    } else if (selectedRole == "investor") {

      r1.style.display = "none";
      r2.style.display = "block";

    }

    navigateToNextStep(this);

  });

}
```

```html
<div class="form__step js-popup-register-step" data-step="1">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-sm-row justify-content-between">
    <div class="button button--blue js-popup-register-button" data-role="investor"><span>Guest</span></div>
    <div class="button js-popup-register-button" data-role="investor-member"><span>Member</span></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form__step js-popup-register-step form__step--inactive" data-step="2">
  <div class="representation-container">
    <div class="radiocustom">
      <input type="radio" id="chk_sophisticated" name="investor_type" value="Sophisticated Investor" checked="checked">
      <label for="chk_sophisticated"> Sophisticated Investor</label>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" id="chk_hnw_individual" name="investor_type" value="High Net Worth Individual">
      <label for="chk_hnw_individual"> High Net Worth Individual</label>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" id="chk_hnw_investor" name="investor_type" value="High Net Worth Investor">
      <label for="chk_hnw_investor"> High Net Worth Company, unincorporated association or trust</label>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="radiocustom2">
      <input type="radio" id="chk_individual" name="other_type" value="Individual" checked="checked">
      <label for="chk_individual"> Individual</label>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" id="chk_networker" name="other_type" value="Business Networker">
      <label for="chk_networker"> Business Networker</label>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" id="chk_corporate" name="other_type" value="Corporate">
      <label for="chk_corporate"> Corporate</label>
      <br>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-sm-row justify-content-between">
      <div class="button js-popup-gateway-button"><span>Confirm</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: There is no method named `getElementByClassName`. Did you mean [`getElementsByClassName`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)? Why are you not simply using jQuery? If you’d like to try moving away from jQuery you could also try [`querySelector`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead. [`clear`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Storage/clear) does not accept arguments; it’ll just remove everything. Did you mean [`removeItem`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem)?

Comment: Happy to use jQuery if that is a simpler route. Thanks for the advice. Would you have a snippet in mind? Removing everything using clear is ok for this dialogue as it's a bit like "start over" which is what I want. That part is working ok. It's the if loop that isn't working.

Comment: I didn’t really mean “jQuery is easier”, I was just wondering why you mix jQuery with the native DOM API instead of using only one, consistently. I don’t think another snippet is necessary here. Just try replacing `getElementByClassName` by `getElementsByClassName` and `clear` by `removeItem`; if you actually want to use `clear`, make this intent clear by removing the argument. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. I tried both of those ideas and the blocks are still not being hidden. There are no errors in the console and the sessionStorage variable is being set and changed by the buttons as desired.

Comment: PS, what's the point of using `sessionStorage` at all in your code? Why are you not presenting us a [mcve]? You've just thrown some HTML and JS which does not present any issue you're mentioning - besides the issues you can read out loud alone by just using the Developer Tools console. Errors like the wrong JS methods etc. What's `navigateToNextStep(this);` at all?

Comment: Thanks Roko. I've used sessionStorage as this is step 1 of a 5 step registration process. The post is not made until step 3 so sessionStorage is used to collect a variable I need in the post and store it for when it's needed later. navigateToNextStep(this); is just calling the next step in the registration process. The only part of the 5 steps that is not working is changing the display property of the radiocustom and radiocustom2 blocks. So I only pasted the relevent part of the registration process that's not working. I'll think about a minimal reproducable example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what you should do .

```
document.querySelector(".radiocustom2").style.display = "none";
```

or else you can set you r1 like this.

```
const r1 = document.querySelector(".radiocustom");
```

You should also clear browser cache to clear any JavaScript that could have logged in the cache.

Comment: This works well. Thanks so much Billions - I needed to clear my browser cache and when I did it was perfect!

Comment: Your welcome, I have added your hack, to clear browser cache so we can mark it as the correct answer. Incase someone stumbles upon it. It will be very helpful when marked correct.